# Feminine noun with suffix -ung that is not the result of a "Verb to Noun process"

Tags: verb, etymology, noun, nominalization, suffix

Do you know any example of German noun that is

1. Feminine
2. Ends on *ung*
3. Is **not** the result of taking the word stem of a verb and adding the suffix *ung*

Or can you prove that such a word does not exist?

Just to clarify, I am not asking for an example of a non-feminine noun with suffix *ung* such as *der Schwung*, but simply a word satisfying the above criteria.

Comment: Welcome to German Language SE. While your question is answerable as it stands, can you specify why you want to know this? This way we can probably give you a more helpful answer.

Comment: @ Wrzlprmft  I am mathematician by education, so I love to have examples and counterexamples to such rules. It is not exactly important, but I was very curious : )

Comment: I've added the [tag:etymology] tag. This seems to be related to etymology in 1st place.

Comment: I am also a math-ish guy, so I am curious as to what you expected a proof of non-existence in a natural language to look like!

Comment: Not sure exactly... But I guess a brute force search through the most recognized dictionaries, as well as interviews with a (large) representative random sample of german-speakers / german language professors all denying any familiarity with such a word would suffice. I think the wording was funny though : )

Comment: A bit out of the box: If we use poetic freedom to leave out the final *e*, then *die Zunge* becomes *die Zung* :) (Same with *die Lung* )

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think that *die [Zeitung](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Zeitung)* fulfills the criteria.

Comment: Sure does! Nice : )

Comment: I am now curious if there are more examples. If so, they seem to be rare.

Comment: Note that [Zeitung](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?bookref=31,591,33) is a loan and is derived from a verb plus *-ung/-ing* in the source language.

Answer (score 34):

I wrote a little Python script (see below) to find candidate words. It takes a dictionary and yields all uppercase words that end on *ung* unless:

- there exists a corresponding lowercase word ending on *en, eln,* or *ern.* For example *bergen → Bergung, kapseln → Kapselung, mitteln → Mittlung, weigern → Weigerung.* The presumed verb must at least have five letters to avoid false negatives due to such words as *den, gen, wen,* etc.
- the word is longer than 10 letters and end on *ierung* (to exclude false positives such as *Balkanisierung* or *Hierarchisierung);*
- removing three or more characters from the beginning results in a match according to the first point or another dictionary word ending on *ung* (to exclude false positives originating from composites).
  That match must at least have five letters to avoid false negatives because of words like *Dung.*

As pointed out by [this answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/57968/2594), this script has false negatives such as *Innung,* which is not found because of the adverb *innen.*
(Though in this case [the origin is a verb *innen*](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=innung), which is not in use anymore.)

This gives you 94 candidates, namely:
*Abforstung,
Abgeltung,
Abhandlung,
Abhärtung,
Abplattung,
Abschwung,
Absprung,
Alarmübung,
Angriffsübung,
Anwandelung,
Anwandlung,
Atemübung,
Atomversuchsübung,
Aufwärmübung,
Ausgasung,
Bedachung,
Bedüsung,
Behaarung,
Beköstigung,
Beplankung,
Bereifung,
Beriemung,
Besatzung,
Bestuhlung,
Böschung,
Deckelung,
Diktatübung,
Dung,
Eisprung,
Entvölkerung,
Erbitterung,
Ertüchtigung,
Fingerübung,
Firmung,
Fleckung,
Gattung,
Gefechtsübung,
Gemarkung,
Genugtuung,
Gesittung,
Halterung,
Häutung,
Hoffnung,
Höhlung,
Hydrierung,
Kaperung,
Körnung,
Kröpfung,
Laibung,
Legierung,
Markung,
Maserung,
Nahrung,
Normung,
Nutznießung,
Ölbohrung,
Ölheizung,
Ölleitung,
Ölrechnung,
Ölung,
Pflichtübung,
Planierung,
Polung,
Protektorung,
Quittung,
Rötung,
Samsung,
Satzung,
Schlafzimmerübung,
Schwung,
Sprung,
Stallung,
Stilübung,
Stundung,
Teuerung,
Truppenübung,
Überhöhung,
Übung,
Umdeutung,
Umeichung,
Umschwung,
Unbildung,
Unordnung,
Unzahlung,
Urbevölkerung,
Urfassung,
Ursprung,
Verstädterung,
Vorübung,
Waldung,
Wehrübung,
Zeitung,
Zinkung,* and 
*Zulieferung*

We can now manually exclude obvious false positives that are not feminine or where the corresponding verb exists but is irregular, short, archaic, etc.
This leaves us with:

- ***[Laibung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laibung)***, for which I fail to find anything about its origin.
- ***[Waldung](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=waldung)***, whose origin is somewhat unclear but does not appear to be a verb.
  (This was first mentioned by [this answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/57969/2594), which made me find an problem with my script.)
- ***Zeitung***, which originates from an ancient verb according to [Grimm’s Dictionary](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=zeitung) (as pointed out by [David Vogt](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/35111/david-vogt)).
- ***Satzung***, which originates from an ancient verb according to [Grimm’s Dictionary](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=satzung)
- ***Markung***, which originates from the archaic verb [*marken*](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=marken).
- ***Fleckung***, which originates from the archaic verb [*flecken*](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=flecken).
- ***Quittung***, which originates from *quittieren* or [its predecessors (frz. *quitter*)](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=quittieren). It’s a bit odd that it’s not *Quitt**ier**ung,* but here I would suspect that the *ier* was added to the verb (as opposed to being omitted from the noun) since *quitten* would not work so well as a verb in German.
- ***Protektorung***, which seems to be a bug in the dictionary, because I cannot find any usage that does not seem like an accident on the Internet.

#### The script

This requires Python 3.8 and Aspell:

```
import subprocess
dictionary_process = subprocess.Popen(
        "aspell -l de dump master | aspell -l de expand",
        shell = True,
        stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
        encoding = "utf-8"
    )

unged_verbs = set()
ungs = set()

while line := dictionary_process.stdout.readline():
    for word in line.split():
        if len(word)>=5 and word[0].islower():
            if word.endswith("en"):
                unged_verbs.add( word[:-2].title()+"ung" )
            if word.endswith("eln"):
                unged_verbs.add( word[:-3].title()+"lung" )
                unged_verbs.add( word[:-1].title()+"ung" )
            if word.endswith("ern"):
                unged_verbs.add( word[:-1].title()+"ung" )
        elif word[0].isupper() and word.endswith("ung"):
            ungs.add(word)

all_ungs = unged_verbs|ungs
for candidate in ungs-unged_verbs:
    if candidate.endswith("ierung") and len(candidate)>10:
        continue

    for i in range(3,len(candidate)-5):
        if candidate[i:].title() in all_ungs:
            break
    else:
        print(candidate)
```

Comment: Good work! This is very interesting : )

Comment: why does Lichtung not appear in the candidates list?

Comment: also, I would not be too quick to exclude *Böschung* (*der Busch*), *Höhlung* (*die Höhle* rather than *sich höhlen*? as opposed to *sich wölben* > *die Wölbung*) and likely *Körnung* (*das Korn*) either.

Comment: What about `Meinung`?

Comment: @Jesko Hüttenhain: `meinen` is a verb.

Comment: @dlatikay: `sich lichten` is a matching verb, but there is also `Licht` (substantive) and `licht` (adjective), so it is not clear.

Comment: Another example would be `Festung`, from `fest` or `Feste`. (There's also `Befestigung`, derived from `befestigen`.)

Comment: Quittierung is another noun (coming from the verb quittieren), but it does not mean the piece of paper, but the process itself. And it is less a proper noun, than just the result of such a verb to noun process.

Comment: *die Lichtung* ist wohl genauso wie *waidm. die Dickung* nicht von *(sich) lichten* oder *(sich ver-)dichten/dicken* gebildet, sondern [vom Adjektiv](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Dickung), im Falle der *[Dickung](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Dickung)* sicherlich (vgl. *das Dickicht*). Hypthese: Alles, was mit dem Wald zu tun hat, gilt :)

Answer (score 11):

Another, less common, word that might  fit your criteria (and that was not found by the script) is *[die Innung](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Innung)* (the guild).

Although it seems that [originally there was the verb *innen* in middle-high German](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=innung), it is not the case in contemporary German.

Answer (score 8):

I have found another one: *die [Waldung](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Waldung)*.

Regarding its etymology, [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Waldung) and [Grimm's dictionary](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&lemma=Waldung) claim that *Waldung* is a collective formation of *Wald* before the 17th century, which, however, cannot be proven. Grimm's also reveals that it may have been formed by similarity to the earlier word *[feldung](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GF02626#XGF02626)*. Interestingly, *Feldung* would be a candidate word, too, if it only belonged to the contemporary German vocabulary—but it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks; this made me find [a problem with my script](https://german.stackexchange.com/posts/57966/edit) that now also finds this.

Answer (score 4):

I'd propose "Körnung" which indicates the coarseness of sandpaper and other materials.  While there is a verb "körnen" for pre-denting material you want to drill, it is unrelated.  Interestingly it is in Wrzlprmft's unculled mechanically generated list but seems to have been removed manually.

There is also "Niederung".